# Do I need to protect access to a Boost MultiIndex's index (the index itself) by a lock?

Tags: c++, boost, locking, multi-index

Assuming I have a boost::multi_index_container and want to access an index of it

```
  boost::multi_index_container< ... > bmi;
  // lock here?
  auto &index = boost::multi_index::get<0>(bmi);   // <-- does this call need to be protected by a lock?

  // or is it sufficient to lock here?

  // access the index (need to have the lock here)
```

When multiple processes / threads access a multi_indesx_container, I need to use mutexes (or something of the sort). But do I need to protect getting the index itself, too?
I guess not, but could not find a guarantee in the docs.

Comment: Are you adding or removing items in any of your threads?

Comment: sure, other threads will modifiy the index. (but getting the index itself... will the get() call return different objects if the multi_index gets modified?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not documented anywhere, `get()` is a [static cast operation](https://github.com/boostorg/multi_index/blob/131e3427ae53a6353411088b4a04bdff81d8e806/include/boost/multi_index_container.hpp#L372-L377), which is intrinsically thread-safe.